# Zsh theme not being applied

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to use `zsh` and the hassle starts already with setting the theme.

- I have `.oh-my-zsh` on my `~`
- I have a `.zshrc` file with the following line:
  `ZSH_THEME="3den"`
- I changed my standard-shell to `zsh` with `chsh -s /bin/zsh`
- The theme is available under `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/3den.zsh-theme`

My `.bashrc` is *untouched*!
So what's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Make sure the line setting your desired theme appears in `~/.zshrc` *before* `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`, otherwise it won't get loaded.

Comment: Post your complete `.zshrc`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, confirm for our benefit that Oh-My-Zsh (OMZ) is installed and in effect, for example normally, after successfully switching to OMZ, not only does the command prompt look different, but if you `echo $ZSH_THEME` you should see on the command prompt:

```
$ echo $ZSH_THEME
robbyrussell
```

- `robbyrussell` is the default theme, for those who have not changed it
- so even if you don't have this, you should have some response indicating what theme you are actually currently using. If you don't see this then you aren't actually in OMZ or there is some other error.

So if that works and you see a different theme than `3den`, view the `~/.zshrc` again. Check if there is any duplicate line `ZSH_THEME=` that might be overriding your `ZSH_THEME=` setting.

No duplicates? That means nothing else is overriding your setting.

Then the only thing left is to source your config:

```
$ . ~/.zshrc
```

- `.` is a shortcut for `source`

You should now see your new theme in use.  If you check, it should say `3den` now:

```
$ echo $ZSH_THEME
3den
```